# Variable table name Select * FROM $tablename

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've made a 'movie' database for personal use in my home, through a website and html 5 video tags which I had done with ease, it included an index page listing all movies in the database, and then clicking on one would link you to a page which would display the chosen movie in html 5 video tags... but tv shows are quite different, I require each different tv show to have a table and then the directory etc of each episode is stored inside the corresponding table...

The pages will look something like this... The index page listing all tv shows (Each tv shows table), which then link to another index page displaying all episodes within the corresponding tv (within the clicked table) show which was clicked and then a final page after clicking a certain episode where you could watch the episode, so if I clicked 'Breaking bad' for example, it would then list all breaking bad episodes selected from a table inside a database and then I could click on a certain episode to watch it, this is why I need a variable table name, I was told it can be done... but I don't know how!

Here's some code that I assume the answer to my problem would look like...

```
    $episodesquery="SELECT * FROM $TBL_name ORDER BY episodeTitle ASC";
   $episodesresult=mysql_query($episodesquery) or fail ("Query to get data from $TBL_name failed: ".mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advance

P.S I'm also having trouble with my html 5 video tags or something, I get ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH after watching something longer than 30 minutes which desyncs the audio, thanks!

Comment: I'd change the database structure, you should have one table for movies and one for tv shows (at most).

Comment: This stinks of bad design. The only time you'd want multiple tables is if the various shows would require different table designs. If the **ONLY** difference between the tables is the show's name, then create **ONE** table, and put in a field to contain the show name.

Comment: Appreciate the comments, if I were to use one table I'd just have to add a field which would be the tvshows name, correct? So it'd be SELECT * FROM $TBL_name WHERE tvShowName=$tvShowName

Comment: @Jakeyosaurus Yes. Could you please post your current db structure? table name + column names (a movie and a tv show would be enough). It would be easier to recommend how to achieve it in a better way.

Comment: http://puu.sh/moc0o.png there's the tables structure

Comment: I'd say that's 3 different entities/tables in one. tvshow, season and episode. You could (should?) even have the views in a separate table, if you want to know which user have viewed what episodes (how many times, at which times)

Comment: Yes, season and episode number are both in separate tables connecting via foreign key, the views aren't though, I only added the view counter as it's simple. P.S The tvShowName is also a foreign key!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enclose the query in double quotes then below is correct

```
$episodesquery="SELECT * FROM $TBL_name ORDER BY episodeTitle ASC";
```

OR you can use concatination to make it clear that you are using a variable, like this: which makes either correct.

```
$episodesquery='SELECT * FROM '. $TBL_name . ' ORDER BY episodeTitle ASC';
$episodesquery="SELECT * FROM ". $TBL_name . " ORDER BY episodeTitle ASC";
```